# Twitter-like database table structure

Tags: mysql, twitter, database-design, tree, database-schema

I am trying to create a database that can be used like Twitter works. That is:

1. Treestructure: Any node can have multiple childnodes.
2. All nodes have a timestamp

Criteria 1 and 2 suggests a table structure based on basic columns something like:

```
NodeID        (int)
ParentNodeID  (int)
UserID        (int)
TS            (TimeStamp)
MSG           (varchar)
```

When viewing any node (**n**) all parent nodes until and including root should be selected, that is easy using the **ParentNodeID** pointer.

**Here comes the caveat:** In addition to the parent nodes all child nodes from the current node (**n**) should also be selected in Chronological order (based on TS) from the table. All child nodes, no matter what child-branch, that belongs to the subtree where (**n**) is the root.

How do I best (better) structure the table for such queries?

Comment: Maybe read about left right trees: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: @Gadget Blaster Thanks! Interesting. As I understand it any child added as "third" to the same parent will instead push down the two children already there one level downstream the tree? Not exactly sure how to implement it, but I will look into it.

Comment: @Gadget Blaster You may ignore my last comment, I read it through one more time and understand it better now.

Comment: Good! Because I still don't fully understand it!

Comment: I grasp the concept but needs to dig into how to efficiently update the left and right values when nodes are added. Seems to be various techniques for that ...

Comment: mysql is a terrible choice for a hierarchical schema.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan then can you give some better suggestions?

Comment: Anything that supports recursive cte. Postgres is one

Comment: I have thought about it and are leaning towards an alternative to a left right Nested set solution, using a complementing table like described here:
http://robsite.net/nested-sets-suck-on-how-not-to-map-trees-into-a-relational-database/
below the "So whats better then?"-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take look at how Twitter have been evolving, and check if your use case is similar enough.

A good start could be this article with database schema examples: https://web.archive.org/web/20161224194257/http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/decomposing-twitter-database-perspective/